# Crossfading Submit Button on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to customize my submit button so that, when the mouse hovers over it, it crossfades to a new background-image position in my sprite. I can easily get it to switch to that position, but I'd like to have it slowly fade instead.

There are tons of articles on how to do this for simple links, but they all essentially position the other images over the button area, and then fade opacities correspondingly. This doesn't seem possible with a submit button, since input elements don't seem to be able to contain child elements (ie. the other background sprites). Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking but take a look anyway

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations

**DEMO**: http://snook.ca/technical/jquery-bg/

anyway, you can still add a click listener event using jquery to any div and make it act like a submit button.

```
$("div.submit").click(function() {
    document.forms[0].submit();
});
```

add the css, for the mouse over

```
div.submit:hover {
    pointer: cursor;
}
```

Comment: CSS3 animation with key frames could do some of that.  For any support besides the cutting edge, I think jQuery would be the answer here, though.

Comment: WOW, that kind of thing never occurred to me, to generate a gradient inside of the actual images that simulates a fade when moving. Unfortunately, I'm not just dealing with colors, but full images, so it is impossible/to-technical-for-my-abilities to make a sprite that does that.

Comment: @willthefirst i added an alternative solution, check it out, it will work

Comment: MY GOODNESS! That's it! If I can turn any div into an event listener, I should be able to just crossfade images, and then make them act like submit buttons! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no consistent way to do this in CSS across all major browsers.

For something like that, you really want [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AAB6z/1/) that shows one example of how you can do this. Just update the `fade` var to change the timing of the fades.

Comment: So, if I can get jQuery to the point of switching background images on hover, how can I tell it to fade?

Comment: @willthefirst I added a working example to show you how. You need the inner div because there's no way to apply a fade just to a background image. You have to have an element itself specified for jQuery to work.

Comment: thanks Josh, it looks like use you use the same strategy as depicted in http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations. I'm trying to do this with native images, and crossfade between them, instead of constructing them via gradients/css.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure but if you make the buttons container (a div sized to exactly match the button) you can give it a background image and then fade out the buttons opacity. Can you give an example of the two states you are trying to blend between? It would help give a more specific answer.

Comment: friendswithwheels.com is the website, just hover over the buttons to get an idea of what I am looking for.